# How to hide the actual url which include query string?

Tags: asp.net

I want to replace the url which include query string so end user only not able to see the original path of web page. what can I do?

Comment: You could e.g. save the parts of the URL you need in a cookie, or maybe even page or session state (usually but not always cookie-based too), then redirect them to an anonymous URL which can then use the saved state to render the page. But they may still be able to see the old URL in their browser history etc. and there are things that can go wrong here. Is this really worth doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Use HTML forms with POST instead of regular links or GET forms.
2. Alter the address bar on client side with javascript, but users can bypass this if they know how to and it's kind of sketchy.
3. Save the state and redirect from the backend if possible in your environment, though this is an ugly method as well imo unless it's a one-time thing because of people landing on your page from some external link.